# Cast an interface to a specific type Angular2 with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, angular2-services

I am creating an Angular2 Application. 
I have 3 facets I can search on. I am thinking to make one interface and three classes who implement this interface.

and I want to make a main Service class that can call the specific class according to the type I am giving.

the interface is:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { FacetType } from './facet-type';

export interface IFacetService {
  canHandle(type: FacetType): boolean;

  getFromServer(): Observable<any[]> | null;
}

export enum FacetType {
    Type = <any>'Type ',
    Application = <any>'Application',
    Company = <any> 'Company'
}
```

and the classes are like:

```
export class TypeService implements IFacetService {
  private type: Type[];

  canHandle(type: FacetType): boolean {
    return type === FacetType.Type;
  }

  constructor() { }

  getFromServer(): Observable<Type[]> | null {
    // Call from Server
  }
}
```

the Service function:

```
export class MyService {
  constructor( private facetServices: IFacetService[]) {
  }

  get(type: FacetType) {
    const facets = this.facetServices.filter(function(item) { 
      return item.canHandle(type); 
    });
    for (const facet of facets) {
      return facet.getFromServer();
    }
  }
```

I am receiving this error in the cmd in service function:

> ```
> Property 'canHandle' does not exist on type 'IFacetService'.
> ```

The idea is to write one code for all and according to FacetType the code will change.

The reason is: in the future, there will be more facets.

any help? a little explanation could be very appreciatable. thank you.

Comment: what is that you are trying to do by implementing a interface into a service. It is not advisable

Comment: The interface is just a hint for static analysis (auto completion). If the actual object value passed doesn't have the method, you can't call it. Casting only tells the analyser, that it's safe to assume that the passed value will be of that type, if it actually isn't at runtime static analysis can't do anything about it.

Comment: I have lots of facets and I don't want to write lots of code for each call becuase they implement different code. Type Facets "getFromServer" is different from Application Facet "getFromServer".
so I am trying to add it one and for all regardless what type I am sending

Comment: Your code seems somewhat convoluted with lots of circular checking and cross-checking. Perhaps you should start with the desired end-result: different implementations of 'getFromServer' in your service.ts file. Also, you can't make an array of Type[] and you should never cast to <any>.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? When I copied your code and made as few changes as I could then it all works, but the in the enum casting the strings to `<any>` is not required with the current typescript version which is why I ask.

Comment: @Duncan it is not required. I copied it from the swagger.

Comment: Cutting the code down to a single file fails to reproduce the issue. Could you try the same thing? If you can reproduce the problem when you put everything together into one standalone file (e.g. replacing the Observable import with a dummy class definition) that might help shed some light on this but otherwise the code you posted looks like it should work.

Comment: I guess the problem is with casting. I tried to cast the interface to type of Application and it works. but how can I cast it according to a type I sending?

Comment: You didn't answer the question: which version of typescript are you using? It may be that you have an older version which isn't able to infer the correct types.

Comment: sorry I missed that: tsc -v : Version 2.3.2